# How to get user information from Shiny server inside Azure web apps using EasyAuth?

Tags: javascript, shiny, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, shinyjs

I've got a shiny app inside azure app service using Azure's EasyAuth.  I can successfully authenticate to open a page.  However, I'd like to get the user information which isn't automatic since Shiny strips headers without buying the full pro edition.

I can think of a few high level potential work arounds but I'm not sure how well, if at all, any of these would work without trying to fully implement each.

1. Put an nginx or apache reverse proxy in front of Shiny that would rewrite headers to query parameters which could then be accessed as `session[['clientData']]$url_search`  Pro: I'm pretty sure this would work.  Con: I think people could spoof who they are by just changing the query in their address and also they'd see their name appended to the url which would make copy-paste a pain.  This isn't a deal breaker because it's just for convenience, not security, everyone has access to everything anyway (at least for now)
2. Access the secure&HTTPonly AppServiceAuthSession cookie from the server and then `httr::GET` myurl.com/.auth/me using that cookie to get a concise json of who the user is.  Pro: If it's possible then I don't have to reconfigure my Docker image like in #1 Cons: It doesn't seem I can readily get the cookie into the shiny so this may not really be a potential
3. Have the client brower access myurl.com/.auth/me through a js script and return those results to shiny server.  Pro: Like 2, wouldn't require reconfiguring my app service.  Con: Don't know if possible but it's the same domain so I think it is.

It'd be most helpful if 2 and 3 could either be quickly implemented or 100% ruled out.  If there's a 4th option that I hadn't thought of then that would be welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out #3.

Here's the R/Shiny code

```
library(shiny)
library(rjson)
library(shinyjs)
addResourcePath("www", "www")
shinyApp(
  ui=(
    fluidPage(
      tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "www/script.js")
      ),
          useShinyjs(),
          verbatimTextOutput("results")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    shinyjs::runjs('fetchUser();')
    output$results = renderPrint({
      parsed<-try(fromJSON(json_str=input$username))
      if(!any(class(parsed)=="try-error"))  return(parsed[[1]]$user_id)
    })
  }
)
```

Here's the `script.js` which would go in a www folder

```
// script.js
async function fetchUser() {
  let response = await fetch('/.auth/me');
  if (response.status ===200) {
    let data = await response.text();
    Shiny.setInputValue('username', await data);
  }
}
```

I cobbled this together with [the JS for R book](https://book.javascript-for-r.com/shiny-cookies.html), [this guide on the JS function fetch](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-fetch-api/), and some disparate questions on `shinyjs`.  I'm guessing if someone really wanted to they could intercept that JS script so that they return whatever they want instead of what comes from /.auth/me but since that's only possible after validating the AD authentication and, in my case, it's mostly for convenience not security I'm not too worried about it.  The good news is that the json returned gives a token that, I think, you could independently verify the identity of.